# Interlacing two lists of objects based on attributes of the list objects in python

Tags: python, list

I have two list of marker objects:

```
class Marker():
    def __init__(self,marker_number, marker_data):
        self.marker_number = marker_number
        self.marker_data = marker_data
```

and what I want to do is this:

```
>>> existing_markers = [Marker(marker_number=1, marker_data= 'a'),
                     Marker(marker_number=2, marker_data= 'b'),
                     Marker(marker_number=3, marker_data= 'c'),
                     Marker(marker_number=4, marker_data= 'd'),
                     Marker(marker_number=5, marker_data= 'e'),]

>>> new_markers = [  Marker(marker_number=1, marker_data= 'aa'),
                     Marker(marker_number=3, marker_data= 'bb'),
                     Marker(marker_number=5,  marker_data= 'cc'),]

>>> interlace_markers(existing_markers, new_markers)

[Marker(marker_number=1, marker_data= 'a'),
Marker(marker_number=2, marker_data= 'aa'),
Marker(marker_number=3, marker_data= 'b'),
Marker(marker_number=4, marker_data= 'c'),
Marker(marker_number=5, marker_data= 'bb'),
Marker(marker_number=6, marker_data= 'd'),
Marker(marker_number=7, marker_data= 'e'),
Marker(marker_number=8,  marker_data= 'cc')]
```

So that when I interlace the markers, markers with the same number in the new_markers list as the original markers list appear after the original marker, but the numbering updates to maintain a numbered sequence. This is my current approach:

```
def interlace_markers(current_markers_list, new_markers_list):

    interlaced_markers = []
    #interlace the markers
    for existing_marker in current_markers_list:
        interlaced_markers.append(existing_marker)
        for new_marker in new_markers_list:
            if new_marker.marker_number== existing_marker.marker_number:
                interlaced_markers.append(new_marker)

    #reset the sequence
    sequence_index = 1
    for marker in interlaced_markers:
         marker.marker_number= sequence_index
         sequence_index += 1

    return interlaced_markers
```

I have two problems here:

1. What is the most pythonic way to do this
2. The original list will likely be large ~10k, and created from an
   external file, but the new list will be small ~100-300 long, is
   there a more efficient way of doing this rather than using lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly, I think this is most easily accomplished with simple sorting:

```
interlace_markers = existing_markers + new_markers
interlace_markers.sort(key = lambda x: x.marker_number)
```

Now if you want to change the numbering, you can do that in a simple loop:

```
for i,marker in enumerate(interlace_markers):
    marker.marker_number = i+1 #indexing is 1 based instead of zero based
```

Note that this works because python's sorting is *stable* which means that the order isn't changed if it doesn't have to be.

This leads to an O(n) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn) algorithm which isn't too bad.

Comment: Great idea with the stable sorting. However, this will not renumber the `marker_number`.

Comment: @eumiro -- fixed.  I missed that part of the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @mgilson will this reproducibly arrange the new marker after the existing marker when they both have the same marker number?

Comment: @Ctrlspc -- Yep.  That's the beauty of a stable sorting algorithm :)